# Почему контент блока наезжает на другой блок?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

[image: >1200px]

[image: <768px]

Использую Bootstrap. Один div на весь экран и второй div (синий) блок тоже. На первой картинке показано поведение блоков при большом разрешении (>1200px), на картинке ниже - при маленьком (<768px).

При уменьшении окна первый div вылазит на второй, как видно на картинке. Как сделать так, чтобы блоки были действительно резиновыми и не вылазили на другие?

```css
.blueblock {
  position: static;
  background-color: blue;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}
.first-block {
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.first-block img {
  padding: 20px;
  max-width: 60%;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid first-block col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="team">
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="row" style="text-align: center;">
    <h2>Meet our team</h2>
    <h4>Lorem ipsum solo dis amet</h4> 
    <br>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="text-align: center;">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="" class="img-circle">
      <br>
      <br>
      <h3>AWESOME DESIGN</h3>
      <h4>Curabitur blandit tempus ptitor. Cum socielerisque nisl cons commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl onsec teet.</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="text-align: center;">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="" class="img-circle">
      <br>
      <br>
      <h3>EXCELLENT SUPPORT</h3>
      <h4>Curabitur blandit tempus ptitor. Cum socielerisque nisl cons commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl onsec teet.</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="text-align: center;">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="" class="img-circle">
      <br>
      <br>
      <h3>FULLY RESPONSIVE</h3>
      <h4>Curabitur blandit tempus ptitor. Cum socielerisque nisl cons commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl onsec teet.</h4>
    </div>

    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="container col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="text-align: center; padding: 20px;">
      <a href="#team" class="btnlink">Meet the team</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--BLUE BLOCK-->
<div class="container-fluid blueblock col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

</div>
```

http://codepen.io/ksider/pen/GpoBGV

Comment: Думаете для ответа на ваш вопрос код html и css не нужны?

Comment: тот код который вы привели в codepen работает нормально, покажите ваш код который вызывает наложение дивов

Answer (score 1):

Нужно в стилях .blueblock и .first-block 
удалить строку

```
height: 100%;
```

Так как "height" указывает определенную высоту.
А здесь хватит и минимальной высоты

```
min-height: 100%;
```

Получится:

```
.blueblock {
   position: static;
   background-color: blue;
   min-height: 100%;
   padding-bottom: 100%;
 }
 .first-block {
   text-align: center;
   min-height: 100%;
 }
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?